# NSURL creation hangs

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

I am trying to create a NSURL for the file path : /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/5EF4C1A8-D8F2-4867-B163-766C691A38C7/Documents/some_folder_name/data.mp4

```
String file_path = new File(documents_path + File.separator + some_folder_name + File.separator + "data.mp4").getAbsolutePath()
```

The file path was created by getting the documents directory and manually appending the rest of the file path. It actually came from Objective C code generated using j2objc (basically java code).

Now, when I execute,

```
[NSURL fileURLWithPath: file_path]
```

, execution is stuck there. I was able to verify in xcode that when I pause, I am unable to come out of NSURL code.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: sorry... updated with actual value. The path was constructed in java code. new File(documents_path + File.separator + "test.mp4").getAbsolutePath()

Comment: You should still update your question with relevant code that fully demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Your updated question is not showing Objective-C code. Please post your real Objective-C code.

Comment: I wrote the code in java and used j2objc to create Objective C code. If I copied the translated code, it would not make much sense because the actual calls to ios FS is done many layers down in call stack.

Comment: not sure why question was down voted. neither the problem or solution is trivial. j2objc generates code that uses it's own libraries which are Objective C translations of jdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you are manually appending paths. It’s better to use default methods of filemanager tocreate folder and append paths.

After that final path should be added to NSUrl.

Comment: it works that way! After moving the creation of the intermediate folder into Objective C/Swift, the URL got created.

Answer (score 1):

It'll work if you write the code in Objc/Swift, but you don't need to. In your google groups post that linked to this, you mention 'mkdirs', but you aren't calling that above. Assuming the path itself is valid, you can do this with the Java/J2objc code, and if you're bothering with J2objc, you might as well, right?

```
File dir = new File(documents_path + File.separator + some_folder_name);
dir.mkdirs();
File dataFile = new File(dir, "data.mp4");
String file_path = dataFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

Should verify that 'documents_path' is a valid form for Java.

Comment: I will verify that.